# How to access variable name of paramater of type Mat inside function

Tags: c++, function, variables, opencv, parameters

I have a trivial question. I want to get the variable name of a parameter of type Mat in C++.

```
int main(){
    Mat cat = imread("/cat.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);  
    function(cat);

} 

void function(Mat& image){  
    Mat img;  
    imwrite("/imageOf" << **What to write here?** << ".jpg", img);  

}
```

For this example above I'd like the file I save to be named **imageOfcat.jpg**

How can I access the variable name of the parameter ?

Comment: Mat objects don't store image name. You need either to pass the name as suggested by @m.s., or create your own MyImage class that stores the name `string` and the data `Mat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the name of the variable from within `function`.
Instead, you could pass the string as a second argument:

```
void function(Mat& image, const std::string& name)
{  
    Mat img;  
    imwrite(std::string("imageOf" + name + ".jpg"), img);  

}

int main()
{
    Mat cat = imread("cat.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);  
    function(cat, "cat");
}
```